# how do i solve this error EPERM operation not permitted

Tags: reactjs, updates, file-permissions

I need help with this, I developed a desktop application using React and electron, everything was fine. The question is that when I try to download an update of the application, everything goes well until the error "EPERM: operation not permitted.open" appears with the address to the folder where the temporary update file is downloaded,

I have tried with the permissions of the folders by disabling the firewall but the error still persists, any ideas.

I don't know if the update configuration code in the Electronjs search engine will help

```
autoUpdater.logger = log;
autoUpdater.logger.transports.file.level = 'info';
// Deshabilitar la consola emergente de actualización automática
autoUpdater.autoInstallOnAppQuit = false;


autoUpdater.setFeedURL({
  provider: 'github',
  owner: 'zerontec',
  repo: 'deskGledah',
  url: "https://github.com/zerontec/deskGledah/releases"
});

autoUpdater.on('update-available', (info) => {
  
  dialog.showMessageBox({
    type: 'info',
    title: 'Actualización disponible',
    message: 'Hay una nueva versión disponible. ¿Deseas actualizar?',
    buttons: ['Actualizar', 'Cancelar'],
    defaultId: 0,
  }).then((response) => {
    if (response.response === 0) {
      
      autoUpdater.downloadUpdate();
    }
  });
});

autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', (info) => {
  
  dialog.showMessageBox({
    type: 'info',
    title: 'Sin actualizaciones',
    message: 'Ya tienes la última versión instalada.',
    buttons: ['OK'],
    defaultId: 0,
  });
});

autoUpdater.on('error', (err) => {
  
  dialog.showErrorBox('Error al buscar actualizaciones', err.message || '');
});


autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (info) => {
 
  dialog.showMessageBox({
    type: 'info',
    title: 'Actualización lista',
    message: 'La actualización ha sido descargada y está lista para instalarse. ¿Deseas reiniciar ahora?',
    buttons: ['Reiniciar', 'Cancelar'],
    defaultId: 0,
  }).then((response) => {
    if (response.response === 0) {
      // Si el usuario decide reiniciar, cierra la aplicación y reinicia automáticamente
      setImmediate(() => autoUpdater.quitAndInstall());
    }
  });
});


app.whenReady().then(() => {
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
});
```

Comment: Please update the question with relevant code.

Comment: I don't know if the update configuration code in the Electronjs search engine will help

Comment: @Leo Did you find a solution for your issue? I'm having the same problem...